# MPAndroidChart line graph remove only top border android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linegraph

I am using MPAndroidChart for line graph. I have some 5 points. Below is my code.

```
 LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    lineChart.setDrawBorders(true);
    lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.fitScreen();
    lineChart.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true);

    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(true);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    lineChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
    lineChart.setScaleMinima(3f, 0f);
    lineChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //set whatever color you prefer
    lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    Legend l = lineChart.getLegend();
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    l.setDrawInside(true);
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();

    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("1"), 5));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("2"), 2));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("3"), 6));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("4"), 8));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("5"), 2));

    LineDataSet d = new LineDataSet(values, "Actual kWh ");
    d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    d.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    d.setCircleRadius(3f);
    d.setCircleColorHole(Color.BLACK);
    d.setValueTextSize(10f);
    d.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    dataSets.add(d);
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    lineChart.setData(data);
    lineChart.invalidate();
```

I am able to do most of the customization. My question is how to remove only the topborder ? Also in the X Axis I am getting decimal values like 1, 1.2, 1.3 and it goes on. I want the X Axis to have values like 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5. How can I do this ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.setDrawBorders(false);
        lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.fitScreen();
        lineChart.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);

        lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(true);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

        lineChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(true);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        XAxis xLabels = lineChart.getXAxis();
        xLabels.setGranularity(1f);

        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
        lineChart.setScaleMinima(3f, 0f);
        lineChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //set whatever color you prefer
        lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        lineChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setDragEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        Legend l = lineChart.getLegend();
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setDrawInside(true);
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("1"), 5));
        values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("2"), 2));
        values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("3"), 6));
        values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("4"), 8));
        values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("5"), 2));

        LineDataSet d = new LineDataSet(values, "Actual kWh ");
        d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        d.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        d.setCircleRadius(3f);
        d.setCircleColorHole(Color.BLACK);
        d.setValueTextSize(10f);
        d.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dataSets.add(d);
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        lineChart.setData(data);
        lineChart.invalidate();
```

**Update**

```
 //to hide x-axis line 
 xLabels.setAxisLineColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: this worked for me. Thank you so much. But the distance between 1 and 2 is too far. How can I reduce that? Also can we draw lines below the line graph instead of filling colors?

Comment: I want to remove bottom border as well. How can I do this ?

Comment: @madhuri H R add this xLabels.setEnabled(false);

Comment: I tried this. But it will remove vertical lines and labels as well

Comment: @madhuriHR check my updated answer and vote up if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This Display Vertical lines

```
LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    lineChart.setDrawBorders(false);
    lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.fitScreen();
    lineChart.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);

    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    lineChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
    lineChart.setScaleMinima(3f, 0f);
    lineChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //set whatever color you prefer
    lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    lineChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(false);
    lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    lineChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    Legend l = lineChart.getLegend();
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    l.setDrawInside(true);
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();

    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("1"), 5));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("2"), 2));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("3"), 6));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("4"), 8));
    values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("5"), 2));

    LineDataSet d = new LineDataSet(values, "Actual kWh ");
    d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    d.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    d.setCircleRadius(3f);
    d.setCircleColorHole(Color.BLACK);
    d.setValueTextSize(10f);
    d.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    dataSets.add(d);
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    lineChart.setData(data);
    lineChart.invalidate();
```

If You don't need any grid lines

use

```
lineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
```

Comment: But this gives horizontal lines.

Comment: so you need just vertical line ok?

Comment: I need only left border, right border and bottom border.